# apt-get dist xenial arm error 64

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources

here is another "I don't know how to handle error 404 when doing apt-get update and it blocks me from using apt-get, ubuntu software and synaptic".

I am running Kubuntu 16.04 on a acer laptop

So my issue is :
when I do apt-get update I get those error :

```
E: Failed to fetch http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:860:f70a:100::2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:860:f70a:100::2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:860:f70a:100::2 80]
```

and this is my sources.list

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http //fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

I really don't get why it is looking for arm64 packages... If somebody could be kind enough to explain to me what is wrong with my apt-get update it would be nice

ps i don't have anything in my sources.list.d folder and i did remove every http: on this post to be able to post the stacks with <10 reputation

Thank you by advance

Comment: Please tell us the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` ([edit] your question).

Comment: Ok, i got it, the issue came from the foreign architecture and `sudo dpkg --force-architecture --remove-architecture arm64` allows me to get rid of the issue but I consider keeping those packages for now, so this is not quite the fix I am looking for