# Unable to locate packages using APT

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am unable to install any package using apt. As an example, if I try to install libgtk2.0-dev package, I see following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgtk2.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-dev'
```

When I click on Updates tab of Ubuntu Software app, it shows this error:

> apt transaction returned result exit-failed

I have tried changing my `sources.list` but that did not help. My current `sources.list` is as follows:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

apt-get update returns with some errors :

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/nv-gie-repo-rc-cuda8.0-trt2.1-20170328  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/nv-gie-repo-rc-cuda8.0-trt2.1-20170328  InRelease
Get:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease
Ign:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease
Get:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease
Ign:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease
Get:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease
Ign:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:7 file:/var/nv-gie-repo-rc-cuda8.0-trt2.1-20170328  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]
Get:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]
Get:7 file:/var/nv-gie-repo-rc-cuda8.0-trt2.1-20170328  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]
Get:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]     
Get:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]   
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB] 
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]           
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [633 kB]
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [605 kB]
Ign:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages  
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [266 kB]
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [305 kB]
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [219 kB]
Get:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,972 B]
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7,988 B]
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,692 B]
Get:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [539 kB]
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [514 kB]
Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [218 kB]
Get:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [172 kB]
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [229 kB]
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [15.3 kB]
Get:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.5 kB]
Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:40 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,544 B]
Get:41 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:42 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.3 kB]
Get:43 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4,836 B]
Get:44 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [4,840 B]
Ign:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Get:46 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en [3,220 B]
Get:47 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:48 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Get:49 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [194 B]
Get:50 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [5,896 B]
Get:51 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [5,896 B]
Ign:52 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Get:53 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3,060 B]
Get:54 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,588 B]
Get:55 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,717 B]
Get:56 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [216 B]
Get:57 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Get:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [356 kB]
Get:59 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:60 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Ign:61 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages          
Get:62 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB] 
Get:63 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [733 kB]
Get:64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]
Get:65 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Get:66 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8,684 B]
Get:67 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Get:68 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 B]
Get:69 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [333 kB]
Ign:70 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages   
Get:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [158 kB]
Get:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.2 kB]
Get:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [62.6 kB]
Get:74 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7,352 B]
Get:75 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [7,364 B]
Get:76 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,432 B]
Get:77 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 B]
Get:78 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [170 kB]
Get:79 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [147 kB]
Ign:80 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:81 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [90.0 kB]
Get:82 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.2 kB]
Get:83 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [69.8 kB]
Get:84 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,760 B]
Get:85 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Get:86 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,916 B]
Get:87 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,236 B]
Get:88 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Get:89 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:70 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages   
Ign:80 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:90 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7,512 kB]
Ign:91 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages      
Ign:70 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages   
Get:92 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Ign:80 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:93 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,410 kB]
Err:70 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:80 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:94 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]
Get:95 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:96 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]
Ign:97 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:98 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]
Get:99 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63.8 kB]
Get:100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [230 kB]
Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:61 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:91 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:61 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:91 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:52 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:61 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:91 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Fetched 553 kB in 1s (323 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Note that missing arm64 binaries is not an issue here. I am ignoring those error messages. Why is it that I'm unable to install regular packages like meld, libgtk2.0-dev etc.? for x86 architecture?

edit: Outputs for print-architecture etc.

```
P64-HJ-HK1:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
P64-HJ-HK1:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
P64-HJ-HK1:~$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal libgtk2.0-0
libgtk2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Candidate: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package ubuntu-minimal
```

This is not a duplicate. I am not asking about 404 errors. They are for arm packages and I can safely ignore. My problem is that I am not able to install packages for amd64!

Comment: Can you ping these IP addresses you mentioned here?

Comment: see here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/834704/apt-get-dist-xenial-arm-error-64

Comment: @Redbob yes I am able to ping those IP addresses..

Comment: @doug I'm ok with the arm64 binaries issues. But notice that I'm also seeing issues for some of the "amd64 DEP-11" packages which is quite strange.

Comment: @Zanna: See above ^

Comment: @DavidFoerster : I am cross compiling for arm64 so that architecture is a valid one.  I'm not worried about the error messages on arm64. The problem is I'm unable to install any of the x86 packages (meld, libgtk2.0-dev etc.)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and `apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal libgtk2.0-0`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : Added